# how to calculate height of scroll content

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I'm developing Hybrid app using `ionic-3`. I want to display vertical line in center of the page and my page have dynamic data so we can't set height of this line. I have display view of my page in below image. I have put div and set as absolute and give border left with 100% height but when i scroll line is no longer. So i just want to calculate height to scroll content and i'll set it dynamically.
Let me know if you have better solution for it.

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: did you tried using `document.body.scrollHeight`

Answer (score 0):

Create Viewchild for your element in component

```
@ViewChild('myScrollY') scrollY: ElementRef;
```

add `#myScrollY` to your element

in component u can get it with below code

```
this.scrollY.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific issue there are some other ways to solve the issue.

1) You could add a pseudo element and position it absolute in the wrapping container
2) Add a background with a line in it.