# how to get maximum scroll height for ion content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I would like to calculate the current scroll percentage of my IonContent (it's an Ionic + React app)

The page layout looks like this:

```
<IonPage>
  <IonHeader>
    <IonToolbar>
      <IonButtons slot="start">
        <IonMenuButton />
      </IonButtons>
      <IonTitle>Page</IonTitle>
    </IonToolbar>
  </IonHeader>
  <IonContentid="main-content"
    scrollEvents={true}
    onIonScroll={(ev) => {
      // ToDo: calculate scroll percentage
      console.log(ev.detail.scrollTop);
    }}>
    {// very long custom component
    }
    <IonFooter>
      <IonLabel>Footer </IonLabel>
    </IonFooter>
  </IonContent>
</IonPage>
```

From the IonScroll event, I can read out the scrollTop which seems to be the current scroll position.
Now I need to get the maximal scrolling height of the IonContent.

**Related questions are**:

- [finding the maximum scroll position of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688595/finding-the-maximum-scroll-position-of-a-page)
- [Cross-Browser Method to Determine Vertical Scroll Percentage in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387136/cross-browser-method-to-determine-vertical-scroll-percentage-in-javascript)
- [how to calculate height of scroll content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339421/how-to-calculate-height-of-scroll-content)

The accepted answer from the first question seems to provide the most complete approach, by taking the max over a selection of scrolling height values:

```
var limit = Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, 
                   document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight );
```

I've extended this by also adding:

```
document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight
```

**The problem:**

In my scenario, the maximum over these values is around 660. But the logging output from `ev.detail.scrollTop` goes up to `680.76`.
I've connected the debug inspector and tried scrolling from the console, to see what would happen for scroll value around 660. I can still see the content move when scrolling from 660 to 680:

```
document.getElementById('main-content').scrollToPoint(0, 680);
```

How can I find the maximum scrolling coordinates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

```
onIonScroll={async (ev) => {
  const elem = document.getElementById("ion-content-id");

  // the ion content has its own associated scrollElement
  const scrollElement = await ( elem as any).getScrollElement()

  const scrollPosition = ev.detail.scrollTop;
  const totalContentHeight = scrollElement.scrollHeight;
  const viewportHeight = elem.offsetHeight;

  const percentage = scrollPosition / (totalContentHeight - viewportHeight);
  console.log(percentage);
}}
```

I don't understand why this incompatibility was introduced though. Wouldn't it be possible to connect the `scrollElement` of the `IonContent` with `document.scrollingElement`? [The standard is still a draft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement) but implemented in all major browsers (expect IE).

Comment: Your answer is really helpful, but was wondering, is the "async" necessary?

Comment: Nvm, ignore my previous question, I tried removing "async" and it didnt work, keeps getting undefined or NaN.

Comment: Thanks heaps for this. I wouldn't have found that! I wonder if this is a better calculation for viewportHeight?
 const viewportHeight = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top  + elem.offsetHeight;